# How to detect zoom in/out button is clicked on google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

In google map `zoom_changed` event can be called by **double click**, **mouse while** or **zoom in/out button clicking**. My question is how can I detect that zoom changed is occurred by *zoom in/out button click* ?

I have tried to catch `event` from function but I got it undefined

```
google.maps.event.addListener(MAP_PROPERTIES.map, 'zoom_changed', function(e)
{
    self.closeInfoWindow();

    if(MAP_PROPERTIES.user_interaction == true && MAP_PROPERTIES.currentZoomLevel != MAP_PROPERTIES.map.getZoom() )
    {
        VRS.TRACE(e); // e is undefined here

        /*My functionalities here*/
    }
});
```

Any of your suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this fiddle in which there is custom zoom controls added. So you can actually add event listeners easily.
http://jsfiddle.net/maunovaha/jptLfhc8/

```
  var zoomInButton = document.createElement('div');
  zoomInButton.style.width = '32px'; 
  zoomInButton.style.height = '32px';
  /* Change this to be the .png image you want to use */
  zoomInButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://placehold.it/32/00ff00")';
  controlWrapper.appendChild(zoomInButton);

  // Setup the click event listener - zoomIn
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomInButton, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
  });
```

or else try adding event listener to this `$('[title="Zoom out"]')`